# Getting reputation while becoming a member of answers.onstartups.com

Tags: support, reputation

I am already a member of stackoverflow.When I become member of meta stackoverflow I got the 100 reputation because of member of stackoverflow already.Now I become the member of http://answers.onstartups.com but I dont get the reputation as I got when became the member of meta.

Comment: Why did this get downvoted?  It's a perfectly good question, with the correct answer given below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answers.onstartups.com is not part of the Stack Overflow trilogy. It's an independent site run by somebody else (on StackExchange's software, though).